# Force Android Chrome to not downsample images

Tags: android, image, google-chrome, size

It seems Chrome on Android automatically resamples large JPG images down to small, low resolution version automatically.

Try this image on Chrome desktop and Chrome Android:
http://msmclients.co.uk/chrome/

I have a project where I really need to stop it doing that.  I appreciate the image is quite large, but it is a sprite and is working as a quicker alternative to separate images.

How do I stop Android Chrome resampling the image?

Comment: https://crbug.com/419744

Answer (score 0):

Try going into Settings => Data Saver => off.

Data Saver funnels data through google servers that compress it, bypassing that may fix your issue!