# Leaflet CRS.Simple on Chrome Android resolution low on zoom

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, leaflet

I'm writing a floorplan mapping app in Leaflet using CRS.Simple.  Everything works fine on the desktop, but in Chrome on Android, the map stays low res when I zoom.  Chrome on Android seems to be the only issue.  It works in Firefox on Android.  I think it simply isn't resampling the image when I zoom in.  It just scales the initial layer.  I'm not using data saver.  It's not an image rendering issue, because it's actually displaying the image at too low a resolution.  The image is a very large jpeg (4688 x 6468 at 4225k).  I've created a http://jsfiddle.net/njeob9c3/1 showing the issue. Here is my html.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="image-map"></div>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here is my css:

```
html {
    font-family: "myriad-pro", sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#image-map {
   height: 85vh;
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 100%;
}

#map-container {
    margin: 0;
    height: 85vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And here is my javascript:

```
var map = L.map('image-map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    center: [0,0],
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 4
});

const width = 609.3,
    height = 406.79245283,
    mapurl = 'https://corporate.ford.com/content/dam/corporate/en/company/community/dearborn-campus-transformation/Existing-Site-Plan-HR.jpg',
    centerx = 243,
    centery = 238.79245283,
    mapscale = 15.9;

var bounds = L.latLngBounds([[-centery,-centerx], [height - centery, width - centerx]]);
var image = L.imageOverlay(mapurl, bounds).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(bounds);
var newBounds = bounds.pad(.1);
map.setMaxBounds(newBounds);
```

On a desktop it works fine.  View the fiddle in Chrome on Android and the resolution doesn't resample when it's zoomed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure to share enough information, code, and possibly screenshots for people to be able to understand your situation. Providing a live example that reproduces your issue is ideal. The [help for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) provide some guidance.

Comment: I've created a js-fiddle that shows a simplified version of my code that demonstrates the issue.  https://jsfiddle.net/njeob9c3/1/  If you view it on a desktop it works correctly, but in Chrome on Android, the resolution of the image is lower when zoomed.  I'm using Chrome 63.0.3239.111 on Android 6.0.0

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bug in Chrome for Android itself, affecting big images.

Try loading your image directly (without Leaflet) in the browser:

https://corporate.ford.com/content/dam/corporate/en/company/community/dearborn-campus-transformation/Existing-Site-Plan-HR.jpg

When I test it, the image resolution is poorer than on Desktop.

Probably the same as [Force Android Chrome to not downsample images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736942/force-android-chrome-to-not-downsample-images), which links to the Chrome (Chromium) project issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=419744, still open at time of writing.

Comment: That definitely seems to be the problem.  My data saver is off, so Chrome is doing the downsampling on its own.  Are there any work-arounds?

Comment: Easiest would be to split your image until each piece is no longer downsampled. You could also convert it into a quad tree set (Tile Layer), which would facilitate loading at low zoom.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to tile my images, although I may do it in the future.  I did just try converting my image to a low bit depth png, and that preserves the resolution.  But there a little loss in speed.