# Javascript Image width different on android and windows

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, canvas

I have an image with the resolution of 9921x7015px. If I load it via the following code (in chrome dev console), I can retrieve the real size:

```
image = new Image()
image.src = "http://example.com/resource.jpg"
image.width // 9921
image.height // 7015
```

If I do the exact same thing on my android phone, I get different values:

```
image.width // 2481
image.height // 1754
```

That seems to be 1/4th of the original size. Pixel density ist 1,25 on windows and 2,75 on the phone but this should not be relevant in this case since I just load it in the background without drawing it.

This is my meta header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Why is this happening? Is there any way to determine the "downscaling factor"?

Comment: This question is related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736942/force-android-chrome-to-not-downsample-images